# query all symbolic links to a directory

Tags: find, hp-ux, links

HP-UX ***B.11.31 U ia64 ***** unlimited-user license.

```
$ ls -al
10 May  9  2011 HORCM -> /opt/HORCM
8 May  9  2011 bin -> /usr/bin
0 Mar 29  2012 core
Feb 18 05:36 dev
```

How do I list the link name and link location (where the link resides), when I know the directory where the link takes me to? I would like to know this for links to directories only. That is the reason I pasted only directories (`HORCM` is a directory) in the code above.

Comment: using the `find` command, but yes, you would have to search through all the potential places.
`sudo find / -name HORCM -type l -ls` would search the entire filesystem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer states, there is no simple task to do that. You have to search the whole filesystem. Here is an approach:

```
find / -type l -ls 2>/dev/null | grep -P " -> .*HORCM$"
```

It uses `find` to search all links, then prints them in a form like `ls -dils`. At the end, the complete output is grepped for the folder you search. It may take a while to search trough the system.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of knowing what symbolic links exist that point to a particular directory or whatever, besides simply searching through the entire filesystem for symbolic links and checking what those links point to.